# A Specific HighChart wont show up in my Phantomjs created PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts, phantomjs, fantom

I have a web page created in Fantom that displays many charts created in HighCharts and I am turning this page into a PDF successfully using a script I created in Phantomjs.

The problem is that I have 4 HighCharts in total but the third HighChart only shows up in the PDF about half the time. The other 3 HighCharts show up in the pdf 100% of the time. Here is the HighChart code below for the HighChart that shows up only 50% of the time.

```
setTimeout(function () { var cchChart = Highcharts.chart('containerCHH', 
  { chart: { type: 'column' }, 
    title: {text: 'Cooling and Heating Hours'},
    xAxis: {categories: ['TRTU39', 'TRTU40', 'TRTU41', 'TRTU42', 'TRTU43', 'TRTU44', 'TRTU45', 'TRTU46', 'TRTU47', 'TRTU48', 'TRTU49'], 
    crosshair: true },
    yAxis: { min: 0, gridLineWidth: 1, minorGridLineWidth: 0, gridLineDashStyle: 'dash', GridColor: '#ECECED', 
    title: { text: 'Hours' }},
    credits: { enabled: false },
    tooltip: { enabled: false },
    plotOptions: { column: { pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0 }},
    series: [
      { 
       name: 'Cooling Single Stage (Hr)', 
       data: [260,350,420,370,130,null,null,null,null], color:'#CCFFFE', 
       animation: false },
      { 
          ..etc
       },
       {
          ... etc 
       },
       { 
           ... etc
       }]})}, 1);
```

I set my phantomjs script with these setTimeouts

```
resourceWait  = 300,
maxRenderWait = 5000,


page.open(url, function (status) {
   if (status !== "success") {
     console.log('Unable to load url');
     phantom.exit();
   } else {
     forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Before Login - moving onto login. count: " + count);
        login();
        console.log("Past Login - moving onto render. count: " + count);
        doRender();
    }, maxRenderWait);
   }
  });
```

This is my render timeout below in Phantomjs

```
renderTimeout = setTimeout(doRender, resourceWait)
```

But it doesn't seem to matter how much I increase the timeouts, it doesn't improve the 3rd HighCharts appearance rate in the PDF.

I am really confused about this situation and was hoping a HighChart wizard could lend me a hand! I really do not think its a Phantomjs issue at this point.